# Cant create local connections in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Am new to Oracle, I cannot able to connect local connection after installation. I tried with `Username:sys/system and password:sys/system`. It throws an error as

> THE NETWORK ADAPTER COULD NOT ESTABLISH A CONNECTION

Please Guide me to rectify the mistake.What is the default username and password for connecting it.

[image]

Comment: What have ypu installed - *just* SQL Developer, which is a client? Is the Oracle *server* software also installed - you've tagged with 10g so maybe it is? Have you created a database (if not using XE), and are it and the listener up and running?

Comment: @Alex Poole..No I have not installed server software..Can u guide me how to implement it

Comment: No listener is up..I have not created database too

Comment: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/